# A good HTML5/CSS3 editor

Tags: html, editor, css

I recently switched from Aptana Studio 2 to Aptana Studio 3 (both as an Eclipse [Helios] plugin), with the hope that the new version will bring HTML5/CSS3 support, but so far, the support was partial at best (no docs/auto-complete).
So I'm now looking for a good web-editor with a good support for HTML5/CSS3,
Anyone have any suggestions?
PS: zen coding support will be greatly appreciated.
PS2: also suggestions about full web development IDEs (which include support for PHP5,CSS3,HTML5,zen coding and Javascript) will be more than appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
GZ

Comment: You do realize that neither are fully standardized/released yet?

Comment: @meder I fully understand that, and because of that I dont expect a tight integration with the specs but a more loose support

Answer (score 3):

I use ActiveState Komodo Edit, which supports HTML5 and CSS3 in version 6.0. Free download [**here**](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit/downloads).

Comment: It seems that Komodo Edit 6 doesn't even support the canvas element (marks it as an error & don't support it's JavaScript API).

Comment: @GZaidman: Make sure you get version 6.0 and make sure your file has the `<!DOCTYPE html>` doctype (HTML5). Mine works fine for both things you mentioned.

Comment: Just make sure you turn on html5 support on code intelligence tab in preferences and reopen the current html5 pages you are editing

Answer (score 1):

Try Coffee Cup HTML Editor, full support for HTML5/CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying out almost all the free alternatives, I have found the paid IDE PhpStorm (V. 2) which support HTML5 and CSS3 quite the way i wanted.
Komodo Edit is also a good choice but I felt it was kinda of in the middle between IDE and an Editor, which meant he lacked in features but was also quite bloated (compared to notepad++, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 7.0 (current version as of this writing), [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) reports supporting HTML5. I'm not sure about CSS3 stuff, though, since I haven't had much time to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans' version 7.1 Beta Release Info they mention support for css3

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/

Comment: yeah Netbeans v 7.1 is quite neat.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late:

Consider [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Notepad++ supports a multitude of languages and accepts [this](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=Zen.Coding-Notepad%2B%2B.v0.7.zip) plugin for Zen Coding.

It is also available for free.

Comment: and also has a portable version...